# Magic in the way R evaluates function arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, non-standard-evaluation

Consider the following R code:

```
y1 <- dataset %>% dplyr::filter(W == 1)
```

This works, but there seems to some magic here. Usually, when we have an expression like `foo(bar)`, we should be able to do this:

```
baz <= bar
foo(baz)
```

However, in the presented code snippet, we cannot evaluate `W == 1` outside of `dplyr::filter()`! `W` is not a defined variable.

What's going on?

Comment: `W` only exists in the scope of `dataset` - so you can evaluate `dataset$W == 1` in the same way.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, this is also related to non-standard evaluation. There's a good chapter on the subject: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Comment: @AdamBethke Thank you! If you paste the relevant bits from that link into an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dplyr uses a concept called [Non-standard Evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) (NSE) to make columns from the data frame argument accessible to its functions without quoting or using `dataframe$column` syntax. Basically:

> [Non-standard evaluation] is a catch-all term that means they don’t follow the usual R rules of evaluation. Instead, they capture the expression that you typed and evaluate it in a custom way.[<sup>1</sup>](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

In this case, the custom evaluation takes the argument(s) given to `dplyr::filter`, and parses them so that `W` can be used to refer to the `dataset$W`. The reason that you can't then take that variable and use it elsewhere is that NSE is only applied to the scope of the function.

---

NSE makes a trade-off: functions which modify scope are less safe and/or unusable in programming where you're building a program that uses functions to modify other functions:

> This is an example of the general tension between functions that are designed for interactive use and functions that are safe to program with. A function that uses substitute() might reduce typing, but it can be difficult to call from another function.[<sup>2</sup>](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#calling-from-another-function)

For example, if you wanted to write a function which would use the same code, but swap out `W == 1` for `W == 0` (or some completely different filter), NSE would make that more difficult to accomplish.

In 2017 the tidyverse started to build a solution to this in [tidy evaluation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).